# Wrong package reference for TopicNameMatches class in both Apache and Confluent kafka documentation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I tried the kafka connect transform predicate examples with debezium connector for MS SQL, and faced the issue with documentation for kafka connect. Examples in both documentations mention wrong org.apache.kafka.connect.predicates.TopicNameMatches, instead of the correct org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.TopicNameMatches:

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_predicates
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html#predicate-examples

```
    predicates=IsFoo
    
    predicates.IsFoo.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.predicates.TopicNameMatches
    predicates.IsFoo.pattern=foo
```

while in both distributions package is the same:

package org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates;

https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/predicates/TopicNameMatches.java
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka/blob/master/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/predicates/TopicNameMatches.java

KIP for documentation improvement should then be issued for both?

Comment: Just to be precise, the classname is mistyped in the question, it should be `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.TopicNameMatches`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: it's really mistake.

For the Apache Kafka docs, I already made a [fix](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/9524), but don't know why it didn't apply (asked about it in the PR).

Update. Fix will be applied in release 2.8